How to NOT trigger a Power Automate Workflow when a certain column data changes?
I have a power automate workflow whose trigger is : When an item is created or modified.
In the flow, I am updating a custom column (say col-x) but this column update is in turn triggering another instance of the same workflow. What can I do to NOT trigger the workflow only when col-x changes? It should trigger for any other change.
Note: col-x can take three values.
Trigger conditions are not helping because mine is an inverse case. It's an inverse trigger.

I guess you need to mention all the columns in the trigger, except the column x
